# Changing setenv.sh in tomcat6 didn't increase Heap size

Tags: java, heap-memory, tomcat6, confluence, catalina

In my Confluence plugin development, my local confluence instance uses tomcat6. (Confluence Version 5.6.5 , OS : Mac OS X)

I need to increase the heap size from the default 512m to 1024m.

I added a new setenv.sh file inside the bin directory of the location below.

../target/container/tomcat6x/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin

And also added the below contents to the file

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

but when i restarted the confluence instance I didnt find the change of heap size being reflected.

Following are the JVM statistics generated during the atlas-run command after the changes are made.

could some one clarify me if I am doing something wrong ??

thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: May be this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04

Comment: Are you sure that CATALINA_BASE=../target/container/tomcat6x/apache-tomcat-6.0.20?  Also, are you sure that setenv.sh is readable by whatever user is running tomcat?

Comment: @schtever I executed the startup.sh script file and logged the CATALINA_HOME variable its point to the same path where I added the setenv.sh file 

../target/container/tomcat6x/apache-tomcat-6.0.20

and I also changed the permission of setenv.sh to read and write for all the user groups, but I still don't have any luck with increasing the heap size.